# how do I create my own layout for a fold out poster in a magazine?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have an A2 poster that folds out, it attaches by a perforation and can be pulled out. I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: How to do what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Ask from the printer of the magazine - if their process allows your poster, they surely tell the wanted input format. They will do it very pleased and detailed if they earn your money.

Prepare a handmade mockup for errorless communication - one copy to them and one to you.

Do not bypass the editor of the magazine!